# Dynamic dispatch without instanceof or getClass() in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, instanceof, dynamic-dispatch

I have the following domain objects:

```
public interface Event {}    
public class FirstEvent {}    
public class SecondEvent {}
```

Then I have another module, that should be fully decoupled from my domain objects, meaning that it knows domain objects, but domain objects should not know about existence of this additional module.

In this module I receive objects through common interface `Event` and I need to act differently based on specific event type.

Currently my code looks like that:

```
if (event instanceof FirstEvent.class) {
    doFirst();
}
else if (event instanceof SecondEvent.class) {
    doSecond();
}
```

It works fine, but static analysis tools and code reviewers complain that I should not use `instanceof` and I should replace it with more Object-Oriented approach. Reflection or `getClass()` is also not an option.

How to do that in Java?

I've reviewed many existing questions about replacements of `instanceof` but all of them suggested adding some logic straight into domain objects. However, in this case I don't want to pollute them with logic specific to just my module.

Comment: Why cant you implement `FirstEvent` and `SecondEvent` from `Event` and then call the method?

Comment: I don't think there's a third option. 99% of the time I would agree with the code-reviewers that you should use inheritance rather than `instanceof` or `getClass`, but there are exceptions.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg not sure if I understand your question. `FirstEvent` and `SecondEvent` are already implemented in another module.

Comment: @PaulBoddington that's also a proper answer for me, at least I'd have something to support me during code review when they start complaining

Comment: what about the Visitor pattern?

Comment: @NathanHughes sure, I'm open. Please post an answer with visitor solution. I don't know how to implement it without adding module-specific logic to my original events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Visitor pattern, aka Double Dispatch, is generally useful here.

An interface is defined with a method for each known Event type, and each event implements an interface method which allows outside objects to call it with an implementation of that interface. The event then ensures that the type specific method of the interface is called with its own 'this' reference so you don't get any explicit down-casting.

```
public interface EventVisitor  {
    visit(FirstEvent firstEvent);
    visit(SecondEvent secondEvent);
}

public class FirstEvent {
    ...
    public void allowVisit(EventVisitor ev) {
        ev.visit(this); // calls the 'FirstEvent' overriden method
    }
    ...
}


public class SecondEvent {
    ...
    public void allowVisit(EventVisitor ev) {
        ev.visit(this); // calls the 'SecondEvent' overriden method
    }
    ... 
}

public class MyOtherObject implements EventVisitor, EventListener {
   ...
   public void signalEvent(Event e) {
       e.allowVisit(this);
   }

   public void visit(FirstEvent e) {
       // handle FirstEvent type
   }

   public void visit(SecondEvent e) {
       // handle SecondEvent type
   }
```

}

The downside of this type of thing is that it becomes difficult to add new Event types because your EventListener interface has to enumerate them. You can 'kind' of get around that with a catch-all method but it's messy and still difficult to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Ruling out `Reflection` is understandable but using `getClass()`should not be issue.

My solution to handle this problem:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DynamicDispatch{
    Map<String,Event> events = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Event>();
    public DynamicDispatch(){
        Event event = new FirstEvent();
        events.put(event.getName(),event);
        event = new SecondEvent();
        events.put(event.getName(),event);
    }
    public Event getEvent(String eventName){
        return events.get(eventName);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        DynamicDispatch dispatchObj = new DynamicDispatch();
        Event event = dispatchObj.getEvent(args[0]);
        System.out.println("dispatchObj:"+event+":"+event.getName());
    }
}

interface Event {
    public String getName();
}
class FirstEvent implements Event{
    public String getName(){
        //return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        return "FirstEvent";
    }
}
class SecondEvent implements Event{
    public String getName(){
        //return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        return "SecondEvent";
    }
}
```

output:

```
java DynamicDispatch FirstEvent
dispatchObj:FirstEvent@72d86c58:FirstEvent

java DynamicDispatch SecondEvent
dispatchObj:SecondEvent@72d86c58:SecondEvent
```

Still I prefer to use `return this.getClass().getSimpleName();` instead of hard coding the value.

I hope above code should be fine with `static analysis tools`.